# Is there a way I can print all the days between two epoch times in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, date-range

```
//[Sat 2018-12-29 13:30:00 UTC]
final long startTs = 1546090200000L

//[Wed 2019-01-02 09:12:00 UTC]
final long endTs = 1546420320000L
```

Is there a way using LocalDateTime I can print all the days between these two times?

Ideal output would be:

> 2018-12-29
>
> 2018-12-30
>
> 2018-12-31
>
> 2019-01-01
>
> 2019-01-02

Comment: Yes, there is... A day is 86400000 milisseconds - you just need a loop. Use SimpleDateFormat for proper printing the way you want

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: *"Is there a way **using LocalDateTime**"* Not until you define which time zone you want the dates in. Also, if you're interest in **dates**, why use `LocalDateTime` and not `LocalDate`?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Don’t do the math yourself, the library methods can do it more reliably and with cleaner and clearer code. And don’t ever use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and fortunately long outdated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LocalDateTime`, for example:

```
LocalDateTime startLDT = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(startTs), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime endLDT = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(endTs), ZoneId.systemDefault());
while (startLDT.isBefore(endLDT)) {
    System.out.println(startLDT.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
    startLDT = startLDT.plusDays(1);
}
```

This loop takes milliseconds and creates instances of `LocalDateTime`. Then at each iteration if earlier date is before later - it's printed in format `yyyy-MM-dd` and incremented by day.

Comment: This works but does not print the last day (2019-01-02) using above dates as example.

Comment: It's because the difference does not make up the whole day. Just add `.withHour(0).withMinute(0)` to the first line (based on your resolution).

Answer (score 2):

## `LocalDate::datesUntil` ➙ stream

Since Java 9 you can use `LocalDate.datesUntil()` for iterating over a date interval.

```
    //[Sat 2018-12-29 13:30:00 UTC]
    final long startTs = 1_546_090_200_000L;

    //[Wed 2019-01-02 09:12:00 UTC]
    final long endTs = 1_546_420_320_000L;

    LocalDate startDate = millisToLocalDate(startTs);
    LocalDate endDate = millisToLocalDate(endTs);
    startDate.datesUntil( endDate.plusDays(1) )        // Returns a stream.
             .forEach( System.out::println );          // Iterates objects in the stream, passing each to `println` method.
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 2018-12-29
> 2018-12-30
> 2018-12-31
> 2019-01-01
> 2019-01-02
> ```

I am using the following auxiliary method for converting your counts of milliseconds to `LocalDate`. I seemed to understand that you wanted to use dates in UTC, so this is what the method does.

```
private static LocalDate millisToLocalDate(long millisSinceEpoch) {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisSinceEpoch)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toLocalDate();
}
```

`datesUntil` returns a stream of the dates from start date inclusive to end date exclusive. Since you wanted the end date to be included, we needed to add one day to it before passing it to `datesUntil`.

**Link:** [Documentation of `LocalDate.datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate))

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

First, consider the built-in solution shown in [Answer by Ole V.V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57875002/642706).

Add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project, for the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class.

```
LocalDateRange
.of( 
    Instant
    .ofEpochMilli( 1_546_090_200_000L )
    .atZone( 
        ZoneId.of( "America/Toronto" ) 
    )
    .toLocalDate() ,
    Instant
    .ofEpochMilli( 1_546_420_320_000L )
    .atZone( 
        ZoneId.of( "America/Toronto" ) 
    )
    .toLocalDate() 
)
.stream()
.forEach( 
    System.out::println
)
;
```

> 2018-12-29
>
> 2018-12-30
>
> 2018-12-31
>
> 2019-01-01

## `org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange`

The excellent [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57875002/642706) is correct, and is likely to meet your needs.

But if you find yourself working often with these date ranges, then you might want to learn about the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library. This library adds functionality to the *java.time* classes built into Java.

As discussed in that other Answer, start by parsing your count of milliseconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC into moments represented as [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) objects.

```
//[Sat 2018-12-29 13:30:00 UTC]
final long startInput = 1_546_090_200_000L ;

//[Wed 2019-01-02 09:12:00 UTC]
final long stopInput = 1_546_420_320_000L ;

Instant startInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( startInput ) ;
Instant stopInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( stopInput ) ;
```

> startInstant.toString() = 2018-12-29T13:30:00Z
>
> stopInstant.toString() = 2019-01-02T09:12:00Z

Adjust those into the time zone by which you want to perceive the calendar. Remember, for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. A moment may be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously being “yesterday” in Toronto Canada.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = startInstant.atZone( z ) ;  // Produce a `ZonedDateTime` object from the `Instant` by applying a `ZoneId`.
```

> zdtStart.toString() = 2018-12-29T22:30+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
>
> zdtStop.toString() = 2019-01-02T18:12+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]

Extract the date-only portion, without the time-of-day and without the time zone, as [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object.

```
LocalDate start = zdtStart.toLocalDate() ;
```

> start.toString() = 2018-12-29
>
> stop.toString() = 2019-01-02

Pass both the start and stop [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects to make a [`org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html).

```
LocalDateRange dateRange = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop ) ;
```

> dateRange.toString() = 2018-12-29/2019-01-02

This `LocalDateRange` class has many methods for comparisons including `contains`, `encloses`, `abuts`, and `overlaps`. But for our purpose here, we want to see all the dates in-between. This class can make a stream of `LocalDate` objects.

```
Stream < LocalDate > stream = dateRange.stream() ;
```

From here, use the same `.forEach` method call to loop as seen in [that other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57875002/642706).

> 2018-12-29
>
> 2018-12-30
>
> 2018-12-31
>
> 2019-01-01

### Half-open span-of-time

Handling a span-of-time is usually best done using the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. If you want to use the code above but also want to include the ending date, just add a day: `stop = stop.plusDays( 1 ) ;`.

Comment: Error:(144, 62) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable stop
  location: class - Adding just the "stop = stop.plusDays( 1 ) ;" doesn't work straightaway.

Comment: @Saffik Try again: [`LocalDate::plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays(long))